# Looking for a sorted C# collection with ability to find nearest neighbours

Tags: c#, sorting

For example.

```
   ISortedMagicCollection<string> collecton = new SortedMagicCollection<string>();

   collection.Add("AAA");
   collection.Add("CCC");
   collection.Add("BBB");
   collection.Add("XXX");
   collection.Add("DDD");

   var points = collection.FindPrevious("BBB").Take(3).ToList();

   points[0] == "AAA"; // true;
   points[1] == "BBB"; // true;
   points[2] == "CCC"; // true;
```

In summary the list should be always sorted and it should be easy to get the nearest neighbours to any specific item.

Note that the list is dynamic. Items are being added and removed all the time.

Comment: You can use `SortedList<string, string>`. Then just find index of key and get next/previous keys by changing index. What is the problem? Synchronization? Is a simple `lock` too expensive for a duration of getting neighbours? Maybe `SortedSet<>` will do too.

Comment: SortedList has poor insert delete performance as it uses a linear array to store all the nodes.

Comment: then use a doubly-linked-list and find the insertion etc point by binary search?

Answer (score 0):

The TreeSet class from the C5 library has what I'm looking for

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm

It has a predecessor function.

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm#T:C5.TreeSet`1|M:C5.TreeSet`1.Predecessor(`0)